# Footnote link does not jump

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, links

This is a minimal working example (in XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ctexart}
\title{Title}
\usepackage[scr=boondox]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{xeCJK, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, hyperref, setspace, geometry, tcolorbox, tikz, circledsteps, framed, extarrows}
\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
$\mathscr{A}$\footnote{This is a footnote}$\mathscr{B}$ 
\end{document}
```

When I click the red link box, it does not jump to the footnote, as if it is an empty link. How can I fix it? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give hyperref a chance and load it late.

This here fails:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,setspace}
\begin{document}
a\footnote{This is a footnote}
\end{document}
```

and this here works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace,hyperref}
\begin{document}
a\footnote{This is a footnote}
\end{document}
```